# compare two data frames and update value in one data frame by comparing another data frame value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames. Examples:

```
df1:
A   B   C
5   7   6
8   1   1
1   0   7
3   4   9
5   7   4
9   2   0

df2:
A   B   C
3   2   1
6   5   7
9   7   9
1   1   2
6   4   5
0   8   6
```

Both data frames have same index.
What I want is , wherever df1's value is less than 5,
I want to update df2's value to 0,  else keep it same.

I tried the following code:

```
df2[df1<5]=0
```

but when I am printing df2, its showing same values as original df2. 
I know I am missing something really simple.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  If you want a non-inplace solution use `df2.mask(df1<5, 0)`

Comment: Yeah. Probably an issue of just not assigning it back.